# Rails create multiple interrelated objects in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `Vehicles` model where each vehicle has a `make` and `model`. When a user creates a vehicle, they can either select from currently available makes and models, or they can create a new make and model. Both `make` and `model` contain no extra data, so they are stored in the `CommonLookup` model I use for dynamic enumerations.

I want to limit `model` choices through ajax based on the currently selected `make`. To do this, I've created a `blongs_to` relationship on the `CommonLookup` model to itself; in other words, any record of that type can optionally reference a `parent` record of the same type in a many-to-one relationship.

The problem I'm running into is actually saving the relationship. My model code, which works for creating non-related `make` and `model` records, is as follows:

```rb
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :make, :class_name => "CommonLookup", :foreign_key => "make_id"
    belongs_to :model, :class_name => "CommonLookup", :foreign_key => "model_id"
    attr_accessor :new_make_name
    attr_accessor :new_model_name

    before_save :create_make_from_name, :create_model_from_name
    def create_make_from_name
        create_make(
            :value => new_make_name
        )
    end

    def create_model_from_name
        create_model(
            :value => new_model_name
        )
    end
end
```

This code successfully creates a vehicle with the associated new make and model, but the new make and model are not associated with each other as I need them to be. I need a many-models to one-make relationship that I can use to easily limit choices. To be clear, this question has nothing to do with the ajax part that is necessary for limiting choices; I'm focusing on the creation of the model instances themselves so that they are related, all from a single form.

I've attempted to set up code in the `create_model_from_name` callback but to no avail; there is no accessible reference to the object created in the first callback that could be used to set up the relationship. What I tried:

```rb
def create_model_from_name
    create_model(
        :value => new_model_name,
        :parent => :make
    )
end
```

But this didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: I looked that up and am unsure of how that points me in the right direction. If I understand the docs right, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` only sets us up to work with one other model. I'm looking to work with two model instances, both related to and created from Vehicle creation forms, and relate the two new models to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by combining the `before_save` callbacks and including a little more logic:

```rb
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :make, :class_name => "CommonLookup", :foreign_key => "make_id"
    belongs_to :model, :class_name => "CommonLookup", :foreign_key => "model_id"
    attr_accessor :new_make_name
    attr_accessor :new_model_name
    before_save :create_make_and_model_from_names

    def create_make_and_model_from_names
        if not new_model_name.blank?
            if not new_make_name.blank?
                create_model(
                    :value => new_model_name,
                    :parent => create_parent(
                        :value => new_make_name
                    )
                )
            else
                create_model(
                    :value => new_model_name,
                    :parent => model
                )
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This met my requirements by setting up a way of creating new makes and creating and associating new models with both new makes and existing makes. The end result is that my ajax request is much easier to set up because I can easily locate the models associated with each make and place these in the options list.